# xcode - cordova project invalid image path issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'd like to validate my cordova project in xCode. The build-process succeeded. All icons are shown on the test-devices and the simulators. The validator shows up this issue:

```
Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 
'CFBundleIconFile':'icon.png'
```

I can't find a key named 'CFBundleIconFile' in my target info. Where is this key set and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a `<key>` in your `project-Info.plist` file and the `icon.png` file should be located in your *iOS* platform folder under *Resources\icons\icon.png*.

Check for the `plist` entry and for the actual file in resources folder (or wherever you store your resource images.

**Info.plist** should have the entry for the generic app icon:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon.png</string>
```

*(the plist file should be located in the main iOS platform project folder)*

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem, it seems that Cordova does not properly copy the icon.png file into the 'Resources' folder.

To fix:

In the '**View**' menu, click ﻿**Navigators﻿ > ﻿Show Project Navigator**﻿

Right-click on the '**Resources**' folder and select '**Add Files to __*project name*__**'

Then navigate to your **icon.png** file and open it.